# Boot Camp, howto manually change the configuration

Tags: macos, boot, bootloader

So I am visiting my in-laws this week, and my mother in law has a iMac with OSX 10.5.  She had a small Windows 7 partition that she was dual booting to with boot camp.  As it turns out, she mainly uses the Windows partition, and the partition was way too small.  She asked me to make it bigger.

So, I used GParted and made the partition the right sizes; however, now the Mac boot manager does not recognize the Windows partition now.  I expected this to happen, but I did not expect boot camp to be so useless afterwards.  The "Untitled" Windows partition in OSX looks ok.  The boot camp UI only lets gives me the option to restore to a single partition.

My question is: can I just manually change the boot entries without the UI ala grub?  Or, how else can I fix the boot loader?

Comment: I'd recommend asking this question over on Ask Different (another StackExchange site, but more tailored toward questions in regard to Apple products). http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found a config file ala gurb to fix this issue, but I did fix it.

There were a a few things at play here.  It looks like I closed some of the tabs I was reading off of, but I will take a stab at writing what I found.

- the osx boot loader look at a (from memory) hybrid of MBR and GPT.  If they are not synced, then they will not show as an option.
- gparted will not sync them automatically
- use "gptsync" to sync the MBR of the disk with the GPT of the partitions

This will allow the OSX bootloader to show you your windows partition as a boot option.

Next, when you boot windows again, it will need to be repaired.  After the repair, everything was good.